# Google sheets - last updated

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

I've seen scripts for this but am absolutely clueless and cannot make it work :(

I want the Last Updated cell (D1) to update whenever the Destiny and Warframe scores update (D4 and D5). These values are pulled from another sheet using IMPORTRANGE. I tried the calculation workaround but that just changed whenever someone opened it (yikes!).

I'm currently running this, but it only updates if something changes manually. Not the automatic changes/calculations:

```
    function onEdit(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Live Scores").getRange("D1").setValue(new Date()).setDateFormat("UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    };
```

EDIT - I understand that the IMPORTRANGE cells do not register as updated. However, E4 and E5 have hidden text that is equal to D4 and D5 in order to apply the conditional formatting. As these change when the imported values change, if there a way to trigger the last updated box?

EDIT 2 - nevermind. I "fixed" it. I put the function into the original sheet and then IMPORTRANGE on that cell into the display sheet.